# Implicit Trigonometric Identity Unclear in L'Hospital Rule Example

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I am (an adult learning math/calculus alone at home) working through some examples of L'Hospital's Rule, and one of the examples makes use of, I believe, a trigonometric identity of which I can't make sense:

$$
\begin{align}
&\ \ \ \  \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\tan x - x}{x^3}  \\
&= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sec^2 x -1}{3x^2} \\
&= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2\sec^2x\tan x}{6x} \\
&=\dotsm
\end{align}
$$

The point of the problem is to practice l'Hospital's Rule; however, my question is regarding the identity $\sec^2-1 = 2\sec^2x-1$.

I understand that $\tan^2x = \sec^2x -1$, but I have no idea what steps were taken to justify the inference of the example from line 2 to 3 of the numerator or the example limit problem.

I'm sure this is just a simple trigonometric identity, but I'm nonetheless at a loss. Any help would be grand.

Reference:
*James Stewart Calculus, 8 Edition, P307*

Comment: $$\frac d {dx}(\sec^2 x - 1)= \frac d {d (\sec x)}(\sec^2 x) \cdot \frac d {dx}(\sec x) = 2\sec x (\sec x \tan x) = 2\sec^2 x \tan x$$

Comment: That step is simply differentiating the numerator and denominator: it’s a second application of l’Hôpital’s ruls.

Comment: Denominator changes from $3x^{2}$ to $6x$. This says numerator too, has been obtained by differentiation as @player3236 indicated.

Comment: Oh my goodness. How embarrassing. Thank you @player3236!